# Python / pygame error with my custom image import module (image animation)?

Tags: python, image, animation, module, pygame

I have created a custom module for importing images and be able to resize it and easily animate them (basicly you say the frames that it have the animation, and it's split the image to the amount you say).

(I know that they are not perfect!)

Here is the module "load.py"

```
#IMPORT MODULES
try:
    import pygame; pygame.init()
    import os
except: pass

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#DEFAULT VALUES    
Image_Frames = 1
Image_Size = (0,0)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def image(name,frames=Image_Frames,size=Image_Size):

    #Load Image
    try:
        img = pygame.image.load(name).convert_alpha()
    except: return None

    #Single / Multi Frame
    if frames <= 1:
        if not 0 in size: img = pygame.transform.scale(img,size)
        return img
    else:

        #Set Variables
        frame_y = 0
        frames_list = []
        frame_height = int(img.get_size()[1] / frames)

        #Loop Frames
        for frame in range(frames):

            #Create a Surface and blit part of the image (Single Frame)
            frame_surface = pygame.Surface((img.get_size()[0], frame_height),pygame.SRCALPHA)
            frame_surface.blit(img,(0,0),(0,frame_y,img.get_size()[0],frame_height))

            #If both values of size are not 0 scale it to size
            if not 0 in size: img = pygame.transform.scale(frame_surface,size)

            #Add it to list of Frames and prepare for next
            frames_list.append(frame_surface)
            frame_y += frame_height

        #Return Frames
        return frames_list
```

The main code (Not perfect, just simply to see the images):

```
import pygame; pygame.init()
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

import load

images = load.image("test.png",2,(400,300))

while True:
    Screen.fill((255,0,255))

    Screen.blit(images[0],(0,0))
    Screen.blit(images[1],(0,400))

    pygame.display.update()
```

And there is this a image that I use (Sorry I can't show images... :( )
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7nghxntor2vbt1/test.png?dl=0

And this is the problem...
What's suppose to happen is that the images are separated into 2,
and the each image is scaled up to 400,300.

But then this happens when I run the code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/idrsygynftb1oua/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.png?dl=0

The first one doesn't scale, and the second one makes something strange...
But that only happens when you do more than 1 'frames'.

If you change it to only do one image, it works fine (code example for main.py)

```
import pygame; pygame.init()
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

import load

images = load.image("test.png",1,(400,300))

while True:
    Screen.fill((255,0,255))

    Screen.blit(images,(0,0))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Any fix? Ask anything you what if you need more info of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually fix!

Your code:

```
#If both values of size are not 0 scale it to size
if not 0 in size: 
    >> img << = pygame.transform.scale(frame_surface,size)
```

should be:

```
#If both values of size are not 0 scale it to size
if not 0 in size:
    >> frame_surface << = pygame.transform.scale(frame_surface,size)
```